# PHP Save special characters html encoded in mySQL

Tags: php

I am trying to convert special character into html characters and then save this to the database.

So if I do this:

```
myString = '123%';

myNewString = htmlentities(myString);
```

I then save this to the database but what I'm getting is:

```
123%
```

and not

```
123&#37;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In HTML, `%` is not special at all. It'd be interesting to know the question background :-?

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't convert data to HTML before inserting it into SQL, you should wait until you are about to insert it into HTML. (That way, if you want to use the data in an email, or a text file, or some JSON, you won't need to decode the HTML first).

Comment: You asked the same thing about an XML string an hour ago. Doing this should *never* be necessary if the data is handled properly. It seems you're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place - consider elaborating on the actual issue(s) you are facing instead.

Comment: You only need to convert characters to entities in HTML if they are one of the 5 characters with special meaning in HTML (% isn't) or if you can't do character encodings right… but even if you can't do character encodings right, % is in ASCII so its encoded representation will always be the same in any encoding that is likely to matter… so you should never need to use a character reference to express %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo htmlentities("<");
```

To turn characters back to readable text

```
echo html_entity_decode("&lt;");
```

But like it has been said, this works for certain characters, for others you will have to use regular expressions.